# Office365 PHPMailer - Appears to send, does not receive in mailbox (no errors)

Tags: php, smtp, office365, phpmailer, cpanel

I have a strange problem. I recently created a bootstrapped CRM which connects to O365 via PHPMailer successfully. I've since duplicated this system on to a new server (new ip) and all of the WHM/cPanel settings match the other server. Here is the strange part, when running my IDENTICAL script, (which I will share below [Item A]) the output is the same [Item B] (suggesting all is ok) but the email is not reaching the inbox. If I replace the login credentials that match the original server, it works. So it suggests that it is an Office365 issue. Now, i've also made a few changes, such as disabling security defaults, i've disabled 2FA manually, i've TURNED SMTP AUTH on. Heck, I've even tried changing the licence type to match the other account, but to no avail.

Finally, it is worth noting, both servers are running the same version (7.*) and same TLS. Both servers are under a cloudflare account with correct DNS settings.

[Item A]

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");


$email_address = "********@yahoo.co.uk";
$subject =  "test";
$notification_body = "test";
$pixel_id =  "test";
$unsubscribe =  "test";

//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require '../../../vendor/autoload.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.office365.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'info@*********.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '************';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";//PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                     //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`
    
    //$email_address = "********@yahoo.co.uk";
    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('info@******.com', '******.com');
    $mail->addAddress($email_address, $email_address);     //Add a recipient
   // $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               //Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@******.com', '******.com');
    if(isset($_POST['cc'])) {
        foreach($_POST['cc'] as $cc => $ccVal){
            $mail->addCC($cc);
        }
    }
   // $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
   // $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
   // $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name

    //Content
    $imageCount=0;
    //$mail->addEmbeddedImage("../assets/img/one-fee-logo.png", "logo"); 
    
    $email_template = 'general_notification.php';
    $message = file_get_contents($email_template);
    
    //$url = '~(?:(https?)://([^\s<]+)|(www\.[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+))(?<![\.,:])~i'; 
    //$notification_body = preg_replace($url, '<a href="$0" target="_blank" title="$0">$0</a>', $notification_body);

    
    $message = str_replace('%unsubscribe%', $unsubscribe, $message);
    $message = str_replace('%email_content%', $notification_body, $message);
    $message = str_replace('%email_title%', $subject, $message);
    $message = str_replace('%pixel_id%', $pixel_id, $message);
    //$message = str_replace('%password%', $password, $message);

    
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $message;
    $mail->AltBody = $notification_body;

    $mail->send();
 

} catch (Exception $e) {     
    //echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}"
}
```

[Item B]

```
2022-10-06 13:33:09 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 LO3P265CA0014.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 6 Oct 2022 13:33:09 +0000
2022-10-06 13:33:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO my.******.co.uk
2022-10-06 13:33:09 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-LO3P265CA0014.outlook.office365.com Hello [18.134.249.179]250-SIZE 157286400250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-STARTTLS250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2022-10-06 13:33:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2022-10-06 13:33:09 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
2022-10-06 13:33:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO my.*****.co.uk
2022-10-06 13:33:09 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-LO3P265CA0014.outlook.office365.com Hello [18.134.249.179]250-SIZE 157286400250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2022-10-06 13:33:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2022-10-06 13:33:09 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2022-10-06 13:33:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2022-10-06 13:33:09 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2022-10-06 13:33:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2022-10-06 13:33:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<info@*****.co.uk>
2022-10-06 13:33:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 Sender OK
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<*****@yahoo.co.uk>
2022-10-06 13:33:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2022-10-06 13:33:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Thu, 6 Oct 2022 13:33:09 +0000
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: "*****@yahoo.co.uk" <********@yahoo.co.uk>
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: "*****.co.uk" <info@*****.co.uk>
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: Reply-To: "*****.co.uk" <info@*****.co.uk>
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: test
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <caY61pb1uIfEh12xPguybhZkpTpJqMOfDjSGoT2pP4Q@my.*****.co.uk>
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.6.4 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1_caY61pb1uIfEh12xPguybhZkpTpJqMOfDjSGoT2pP4Q"
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_caY61pb1uIfEh12xPguybhZkpTpJqMOfDjSGoT2pP4Q
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: test
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_caY61pb1uIfEh12xPguybhZkpTpJqMOfDjSGoT2pP4Q
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_caY61pb1uIfEh12xPguybhZkpTpJqMOfDjSGoT2pP4Q--
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2022-10-06 13:33:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 OK <caY61pb1uIfEh12xPguybhZkpTpJqMOfDjSGoT2pP4Q@my.*****.co.uk> [Hostname=CWLP123MB4851.GBRP123.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
2022-10-06 13:33:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2022-10-06 13:33:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
```

Thank you in advance, but I truly feel like I've exhausted everything.

Comment: As you say, this shows a successful submission, and PHPMailer's involvement ends there. The most obvious thing to do is to look in your spam folder and see if the messages are going in there. The next thing is to look out for bounce messages coming back to your `Sender` address (by default, the same as your `From` address).

Comment: @Synchro and there it is! a full inbox of bounce backs... Remote Server returned '550 5.7.708 Service unavailable. Access denied, traffic not accepted from this IP. For more information please go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=526653 AS(8561) [LOYP123MB2813.GBRP123.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]'

Comment: @Synchro funny thing, when I send an email directly from the inbox, I have no issues either.

Comment: Glad you found them! Well, if you send through their web interface, you're not sending from your IP. You may be running into SPF issues, so check that you have appropriate DNS records in place to permit that.